# I have a div that needs to be added to another div when a specific button is clicked. How do i do it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button in the HTML file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="submitNewBatch">Submit</button>
```

Which on clicked runs a jquery .click() method which appends a div given below

```
<div class="col-md-5 cardDisplayingBatches">
    <h2>Batch #</h2><hr />
    <h3>Info related to this</h3>
</div>
```

to an already existing div on the HTML page. How should I do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a relevant access to HTML element...

```
<div class="col-md-5 cardDisplayingBatches">
    <h2>Batch #</h2><hr />
    <h3>Info related to this</h3>
</div>
```

The first i see was a relevant class named cardDisplayingBatches so in my jQuery code...

```
$('#submitNewBatch').on('click',function(){
  $('.cardDisplayBatches').append('<div />', {
     text: 'blablabla',
     class: 'aClassIfYouWantStyle'
  });
});
```

In the otherwise you should see jQuery documentation for understand how to control of events (".on") and how to (".append") new elements over existing one.